# OO MYSQLI num_rows always = -1

Tags: php, html, mysqli, mysql-num-rows

I want to just check if the username already exists within the database for my signup page, to do this I figure I can just do a select query with the input username and see how many results I get back. However, num_rows is always = -1 The test username I'm using is in the database twice, so when I enter it, it should go to the else and print "this user already exists". I'm kind of new to mysqli as well, so if you see any errors with that, your feedback would be greatly appreciated.

My PHP is here:

```
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    $connection = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","DB");
                    if($connection->connect_errno){
                            echo "Failed to connecto MYSQL: (" . $connection->connect_errno . ") " . $connection-> connect_error;
                    }
                    else{
                            $username = $_POST['username'];
                            $password = $_POST['password'];
                            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                            $check_exist = $connection->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?");
                            $check_exist->bind_param('s', $username);
                            $username = $connection->real_escape_string($username);
                            $check_exist->execute();
                            $check_exist->store_result();
                            $numRows = $check_exist->num_rows();
                            if($numRows = -1){
                                    echo "$numRows";
                                    $enter_user = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)");
                                    $enter_user->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
                                    $enter_user->execute();
                                    $enter_user->store_result();
                                    $check_exist->close();
                                    $enter_user->close();
                                    $connection->close();
                            }
                            else{
                                    echo "This user already exists.";
                                    $check_exist->close();
                                    $connection->close();
                            }
                    }
            }
            ?>
```

Sorry for the formatting, I'm a bit new here...

Comment: `$numRows = -1` <-- you are always assigning $numRows a value of -1

Comment: You should probably just add a `UNIQUE` constraint to the `username` column in your `users` table. Relying on a `SELECT` before inserting leaves a tiny window for duplicate records to be inserted. This can lead to serious security issues.

Comment: @JohnConde So I changed it from = to == and now it always defaults to Else... even if the user doesn't exist.

Comment: @Doncho, what makes you think it `num_rows()` should return -1 if no rows were found? My reading of [the docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) suggests that this should return 0.

Comment: I've figured it out, it works now. Thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The line " if($numRows = -1){ " means you want to code " if($numRows == -1){ "  and this sets $numRows value to -1.

You can use " if(!$numRows){ ".